# vb.net sql command cannot delete

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have the following code in vn.net :

```
     Dim opdragdeleteNuloesskattings As New SqlCommand
    konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=SkeduleringDatabasis;Integrated Security=True"
    konneksie.Open()
    opdragdeleteNuloesskattings.Connection = konneksie
    opdragdeleteNuloesskattings.CommandText = " DELETE() " & _
         " FROM Oesskattings " & _
         " WHERE  ton_skat_tot = 0 "


    konneksie.Close()

    MsgBox("Blokke met geen oesskattings uitgevee")
```

I get the error message (Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '(') on the line opdragdeleteNuloesskattings.ExecuteNonQuery().

I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query must be

```
DELETE Oesskattings WHERE  ton_skat_tot = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`DELETE` is not a function. Remove the `()` after the `DELETE` statement:

```
  Dim opdragdeleteNuloesskattings As New SqlCommand
    konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=SkeduleringDatabasis;Integrated Security=True"
    konneksie.Open()
    opdragdeleteNuloesskattings.Connection = konneksie
    opdragdeleteNuloesskattings.CommandText = " DELETE " & _
         " FROM Oesskattings " & _
         " WHERE  ton_skat_tot = 0 "
```